# Updated heroku stack and now having will_paginate error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, will-paginate

So I updated my heroku stack on my web app and am using ruby 3.2.2 with will_paginate 4.0, but am now receiving an error on one of my pagination pages. The specific error I'm getting is

```
2023-06-15T00:33:11.759517+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 2.6ms | Allocations: 1025)
2023-06-15T00:33:11.759543+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 2.7ms | Allocations: 1069)
2023-06-15T00:33:11.759701+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 2.5ms | Allocations: 2352)
2023-06-15T00:33:11.760282+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-06-15T00:33:11.760282+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 3)):
2023-06-15T00:33:11.760282+00:00 app[web.1]: 13:   <h3><%= link_to "Create New Dude", new_user_path %></h3>
2023-06-15T00:33:11.760283+00:00 app[web.1]: 14: <% end %>
2023-06-15T00:33:11.760283+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:
2023-06-15T00:33:11.760284+00:00 app[web.1]: 16: <%= will_paginate %>
2023-06-15T00:33:11.760284+00:00 app[web.1]: 17:
2023-06-15T00:33:11.760284+00:00 app[web.1]: 18: <table>
2023-06-15T00:33:11.760284+00:00 app[web.1]: 19:   <thead>
2023-06-15T00:33:11.760284+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-06-15T00:33:11.760285+00:00 app[web.1]: app/views/users/index.html.erb:16
```

With the actual code being

```
<%= will_paginate %>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th></th> <!-- Icon -->
    ... a bunch of stuff you don't need to see ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= render @users %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

I can't find any clear documentation on will_paginate 4.0 on why this would be throwing that specific error of `wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 3)`. The only thing I can find is the new basic will_paginate use here https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate. Do I need to somehow bundle my table that I used to paginate into a new structure?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I didn't find an example in the docs that only uses `will_paginate` without a variable. Did you try using `<%= will_paginate @users %>` too? Btw, did you see the comment in the `will_paginate` docs that `will_paginate` is in maintenance mode and will not get any new updates. When you are already updating your dependencies, you might want to consider replacing `will_paginate` with an alternative like `pagy` or `kaminari`

Comment: I did indeed try with @users, but that didn't work either. I'll check out pagy and kaminari, thanks for the tip

Comment: @spickermann I just got things working with pagy. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The new version of `will_paginate` no longer takes an options hash as its third argument. Instead, all of the options should be passed as keyword arguments. So, your code should be changed to:

```
<%= will_paginate @users, per_page: 10 %>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th></th> <!-- Icon -->
    ... a bunch of stuff you don't need to see ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= render @users %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= will_paginate @users, per_page: 10 %>
```

The `per_page` option is used to specify how many records should be displayed per page. In this case, we are setting it to 10.

You can also pass other options to `will_paginate` as keyword arguments. For example, you could pass the `renderer` option to specify a custom pagination renderer.